# Custom validation using Angular material

Tags: angular, validation, angular-material

I want to to do some instant validation on if email has been used or not? I got it to work to check if the email is in use or not, and to have other checks like making sure the input field is not empty, or in the incorrect format.

However, I want to have it displayed (on the html side) on the spot that the email is not available.

```
public email = new FormControl('',[Validators.required,Validators.email]);
public emailValid:boolean;


ngOnInit() {
    this.thisForm=this.formBuilder.group({
      email: this.email,})}

<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Email" formControlName='email' (change)='checkEmail($event)'>
    <mat-error *ngIf="email.invalid">{{UnavailableEmail()}}</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>


UnavailableEmail()
  {
    if(this.email.hasError('required'))
    {
      return "Please enter value"; //works
    }
    else if(this.email.hasError('email'))
    {
      return "Incorrect email format";//works
    }
    else if(this.emailValid==false){
      console.log('email in use');//works
      return "Email in use";<-- doesn't display like I want it to
    }
  }

checkEmail(e:any) //Ignore
  {this.emailValid=false;
    let param:iEmailCheck={
      email:e.target.value,
    }
    this.service.CheckEmail(param).subscribe(val=> //returns a count
      {
        if(val[0].numofemail>=1)
        {this.UnavailableEmail();
        }
        else{
          this.emailValid=true;
          console.log(this.emailValid);
        }
      });
  }
```

Input field should just go invalid (red) with the appropriate message displaying.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding this correctly you need an async validator. That will allow you to validate the value with async operation like API call. You can combine that with other validators as well.

Please find this good article which explains that - 
https://engineering.datorama.com/implementing-async-validators-in-angular-reactive-forms-fdf67c3d0e12

for more details -

https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#async-validation

I hope it would be helpful.